# What's the origin of "One does not simply Telnet into Mordor"?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, meme

While I realise that it's a parody on "One does not simply *walk* into Mordor!" (I believe it's a statement made by Boromir), I was wondering where that particular meme comes from. The connection (no pun intended) between Mordor and the Telnet Protocol is just so arbitrary.

Comment: The [One Does Not Simply X Into Mordor](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor) snowclone/image macro/meme seems to have originated in the Something Awful forums in 2004.

Comment: @Plutor That should probably be an answer.

Comment: While telnetting into mordor is certainly a bad idea, one *can* in fact, SSH into mordor. However, this involves getting Sauron's public key, which no one has managed yet.

Comment: @FakeName: Don't you mean his *private* key?

Comment: Saruman had one.

Comment: +1 Wow, what a question, I didn't expect this. One up of creativity.

Comment: @Secko: This somehow sounds like sarcasm, but there does seem to be an upvote at 23:21. Now, I'm confused :)

Comment: @bitmask No, it's not sarcasm. I really like the question, and I up voted. Why does it sound like sarcasm?

Comment: @Secko: I think -- in retrospect -- it was kindof a silly question :)

Comment: @bitmask Yes, but I didn't know about the parody on that Boromir quote from the movie. :)

Comment: "One does not simply walk into mordor"..."Yes you do. You totally do."  - http://www.i-am-bored.com/bored_link.cfm?link_id=9868

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to Know Your Meme, the "One Does Not Simply X Into Mordor" snowclone/image macro/meme [seems to have originated](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor) in the Something Awful forums in 2004. Lots of great examples of other ones (including puns) on that page.

Comment: That's how you turn a nonchalant comment into 145 rep :)

Comment: @bitmask More like 355 and rising

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it is arbitrary.  That's what happens with memes.  It started with "one does not simply walk into Mordor," as you said, then various people just posted "one does not simply walk into x" and "one does not simply x into Mordor" for all x they could think of, and someone just happened to put telnet into it.  There's nothing deeper about it, it's just the nature of memes.

Comment: How disappointing - I expected a weird back-story, there.

Comment: @bitmask if it'll make you feel better, I'll try and think of a good story for it tomorrow.

Comment: The meme has actually gone so far as "One does not simply *x*".

Answer (score 11):

It might be related to [the custom of naming computers after LotR characters

[image]

and Mordor might then be the name of a Network that is claimed to be difficult to access without permission.

However, Telnet is also used for [MUDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD), and indeed there is [at least one LotR MUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Towers_%28MUD%29) with [telnet access](http://t2tmud.org/connect.php). So, this might refer to a MUD and a difficulty that is most likely so high that playing for the good side one could not simply get to Mordor. However I'm just speculating here, maybe someone who has played LotR MUDs can confirm/falsify this.

Comment: +1 for MUDs! That was the most likely source of the meme

Comment: +1 for MUDs! This was the answer I first thought of, but dismissed with the thought that no one except me still remembered them. Glad to see I'm wrong; maybe the Mud I'm still on will find more players again, some day :)

Comment: I object to the characterization of LotR and SW as "equally dorky" ;)

Comment: @Jagd: To paraphrase Tuvok; LotR is to SW what Kal-toh is to Chess ...

Comment: @bitmask Using a ST:VOY quotation to compare LotR to SW, to boldly compare where no Vulcanian... nevermind. Fun fact: there's an actual _thesis_ on Kal-toh: http://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/10012/5882/1/Anderson_Terry.pdf

Answer (score 10):

I have not read the LOTRs books, but I have come across this meme on our servers. I have noticed UNIX servers named **mordor** (and **gondor** too) and directory paths such as **/home/mordor**.

Once some log files I needed were stored in one of these, but when I tried to access them I found out that I lacked the required permissions. Then of course, someone said "One does not simply *cd* (change directory) into mordor".

If one tries to telnet into a server named mordor, one usually gets the smug response "One does not simply telnet into mordor. One uses [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)."

Comment: I am tempted to give you a +1 for having a server named Mordor. But then you have not read LotR, so I can't really.

Comment: What if I tell you I haven't even seen the movie beyond the point where Gandalf says "You shall not pass!" ?

Comment: You are asking for a dowvote.....

Comment: Who is that sysadmin that allows usernames such as `mordor`? He should be cast into `/dev/mountdoom`.

Comment: What about this evil One Ring that corrupts files?

Comment: @Janoma I actually have a /dev/mountdoom. It's a symlink to /dev/null, and I have configured devfs to recreate it at boot.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a spin on the Star Wars telnet.  If you're not familiar with Star Wars telnet, open up a command prompt and type telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl